# Divs inside another, shows up when .slideDown() is used in the outer div with Jquery and IE8

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, zend-form, ie8-compatibility-mode

The above code works well in all browsers except in IE8 where it only works in compatibility-mode. I removed all the markup inside the DIVs, there where huge TABLEs.
In IE8 when I check the checkbox('rf'), it is suposed to show only two DIVS(#frmRF and #frmAntenas), but it's also showing the DIV(#frmTX), if you think the markup is not ok, it was generated by Zend_Form, I'd like to not have a hidden for each checkbox I create.

```
 <script>
$('input[name="rf"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("#frmRF").show();
        $("#frmAntenas").slideDown();
    }else{
        $("#frmRF").slideUp('slow');
        if(!$('input[name="tx"]').is(':checked'))
            $("#frmAntenas").slideUp('slow');
    }
});
</script>

<TABLE>
<TR>
    <TD>
        <INPUT value=0 type=hidden name=rf ><INPUT id=rf value=1 type=checkbox name=rf> <FONT class=legenda>RF</FONT>
    </TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>

<div id=frmAntenas style="display:none;">
<fieldset> 
<legend>Especificações Técnicas da Solicitante:</legend>

    <div style='margin-top: 10px' id='frmRF' style="display:none;">

    </div>

    <div style='margin-top: 10px' id='frmTX' style="display:none;">

    </div>

</fieldset> 
</div>
```

Comment: I'v just tried replacing 'input[name="rf"]' with 'input[id="rf"]', but no sucess so far.

Comment: There is no imput with name=tx in the above example and you are referencing it. also  -there are two inputs named rf, which is not good for your code

Comment: I didn't paste it because its not used to reproduce the problem, dis-consider that input. And also, as I said, Zend_Form automatically create two inputs for every checkbox, if you know how to avoid this, I'd happy to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all sorry, I have no clue how to comment, don't see any button for it.
I think I've had a similar problem for a while and I have turned off slidedown for IE. I think this is just something IE doesn't handle too well..
So I think you should try this and see if it works:

```
   <script>
    $('input[name="rf"]').change(function(){
    var speed  = $.browser.msie ? 0 : "slow";
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $("#frmRF").show();
            $("#frmAntenas").show(speed);
        }else{
            $("#frmRF").hide(speed);
            if(!$('input[name="tx"]').is(':checked'))
                $("#frmAntenas").hide(speed);
        }
    });
    </script>
```

I believe slideup/down does the same as showing and hiding stuff ("slow"), so i adjusted that.

Lauw

Edit:

It worked for me when I put it online and changed your HTML to the following:

```
<div id=frmAntenas style="display:none;">
<fieldset> 
<legend>Especificações Técnicas da Solicitante:</legend>

    <div id='frmRF' style="display:none; margin-top: 10px">

    </div>

    <div id='frmTX' style="display:none; margin-top: 10px">

    </div>

</fieldset> 
</div>
```

The thing here is that you were defining 'style' twice on the div, so it did not catch on to the display:none;
Editted answer after commenting.
Hope this solves it,

Lauw

Comment: I have already tested with speed '0' or default, no sucess so far. The solution I've found was to use jQuery version 1.4.2, I still don't know why newer versions like 1.4.2+ screw the sliding function in IE...

Comment: I've just put it online myself, and it didnt work at all, what fixed it is changing the HTML markup.
div style='margin-top: 10px' id='frmRF' style="display:none;">

You can only define 'style' once every div, so put this together to:
    <div id='frmTX' style="display:none; margin-top: 10px">
for both, and that should work (does for me).